# Expected value and modulo

Tags: probability-theory, modular-arithmetic, random-variables

Let $X \in \mathbb{N}$ be some discrete RV and define $Y = X \mod k$.

The value of $Y$ is the representative in the coset of $X \mod k$ in $[0, k-1]$.

For example if $X = 9$ and $k = 4$ then $Y = 1$.

How can we relate $E[X]$ and $E[Y]$?

Can we prove that they are close? (depends on some parameters, ofc)

Edit:
It appears the more information is needed to answer here.

Assume X is distributed according to the binomial distribution $Bin(n, p)$

Answer (score 0):

By definition, we have $E(X)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty P(X=n)\cdot n$. Given the relationship between $X$ and $Y$, it follows that $$E(Y)=\sum_{n=0}^{k-1}\left(\sum_{i\equiv n\pmod{k}}P(X=i)\right)\cdot n.$$

Without more information about $X$, I'm not sure if you can say anything more precise. I will gladly update if more info is added to the question.

Comment: I edited the question.